# Gouping and suming multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables one is **products** that has productid, productname, customerid1 and quantity
and another **customers** table that has customerid2,customername and dates

what i want to do is collect all the customerid2 from customers table between two dates.
then match those ids to customerid1 in the products table with a join.
then group all the products by name sum their quantity,
then group all the customers by name for each product and sum their total quantity.

edit: I could use a subquery if necessary or seperate queries entirely. whatever works

```
**customers**
Column      ,   Column,    Column

customerid2:1,  name:jon,   date:2020
customerid2:2,  name:steve, date:2020
customerid2:3,  name:ted,   date:2020
customerid2:4,  name:ned,   date:2020


**products**
Column      , Column      ,     Column      ,  Column

productid:3 , productname:car,   customerid1:1,  qty,5
productid:3 , productname:car,   customerid1:2,  qty,5
productid:1 , productname:boat,  customerid1:3,  qty,1
productid:1 , productname:boat,  customerid1:4,  qty,2
productid:3 , productname:car,   customerid1:1,  qty,5
```

the final output should be:

```
 car total:15
 customer id:1   name:jon     qty:10
 customer id:2    name:steve   qty:5*

 boat total:3
 customer id:3   name:ted   qty:1
 customer id:4    name:ned    qty:2
```

my code:

```
$sql = SELECT customerid2, name, date, productname, SUM(qty)
       FROM customers
       JOIN ON customerid2 = customerid1
       WHERE date BETWEEN '2019' AND '2020'
       GROUP BY productid, customerid2
       ORDER BY qty
```

Comment: Hi, tony!  Welcome to StackOverflow!  What is the result of the code that you have listed here as your own?

Comment: Post a SHOW CREATE TABLE for each involved table.

Comment: its returning nothing i think the SUM(qty) is breaking the output

Answer (score 0):

Mysql can't make such an output, but on application level  you can use this query, to buld what ever you need

This query:

```
SELECT 
  c.customerid2, c.name,p.productname,SUM(qty) total, p1.total_sum
FROM customer c inner JOIN products p ON c.customerid2 = p.customerid1
inner Join (SELECT productid, SUM(qty) total_sum FROM products GROUP BY productid) p1 
  ON p.productid = p1.productid 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2019' AND '2020'
GROUP by c.customerid2, c.name,p.productid,p.productname
ORDER by total DESC;
```

To get a json object as you wanted you need  this

```
SELECT
    json_object('product', CONCAT( total_sum,' ',productname), 'customer',json_result) json_result
FROM
    (SELECT  
        productname
        ,totaL_SUM
        ,JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('customerid', customerid2, 'name', name,'total', total)) json_result
    FROM
        (SELECT 
          c.customerid2, c.name,p.productname,SUM(qty) total, p1.total_sum
        FROM customer c inner JOIN products p ON c.customerid2 = p.customerid1
        inner Join (SELECT productid, SUM(qty) total_sum FROM products GROUP BY productid) p1 
          ON p.productid = p1.productid 
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2019' AND '2020'
        GROUP by c.customerid2, c.name,p.productid,p.productname
        ORDER by total DESC) t2
    GROUP BY productname,total_sum) t3
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products (
>   `productid` INTEGER,
>   `productname` VARCHAR(4),
>   `customerid1` INTEGER,
>   `qty` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO products
>   (`productid`, `productname`, `customerid1`, `qty`)
> VALUES
>   ('3', 'car', '1', '5'),
>   ('3', 'car', '2', '5'),
>   ('1', 'boat', '3', '1'),
>   ('1', 'boat', '4', '2'),
>   ('3', 'car', '1', '5');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customer (
>   `customerid2` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(5),
>   `date` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO customer
>   (`customerid2`, `name`, `date`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'jon', '2020'),
>   ('2', 'steve', '2020'),
>   ('3', 'ted', '2020'),
>   ('4', 'ned', '2020');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   c.customerid2, c.name,p.productname,SUM(qty) total, p1.total_sum
> FROM customer c inner JOIN products p ON c.customerid2 = p.customerid1
> inner Join (SELECT productid, SUM(qty) total_sum FROM products GROUP BY productid) p1 
>   ON p.productid = p1.productid 
> WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2019' AND '2020'
> GROUP by c.customerid2, c.name,p.productid,p.productname
> ORDER by total DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> customerid2 | name  | productname | total | total_sum
> ----------: | :---- | :---------- | ----: | --------:
>           1 | jon   | car         |    10 |        15
>           2 | steve | car         |     5 |        15
>           4 | ned   | boat        |     2 |         3
>           3 | ted   | boat        |     1 |         3
> ```

> ```
> SELECT json_object('product', CONCAT( total_sum,' ',productname), 'customer', 
> json_object('customerid', customerid2, 'name', name,'total', total)) json_result
> FROM
> (SELECT 
>   c.customerid2, c.name,p.productname,SUM(qty) total, p1.total_sum
> FROM customer c inner JOIN products p ON c.customerid2 = p.customerid1
> inner Join (SELECT productid, SUM(qty) total_sum FROM products GROUP BY productid) p1 
>   ON p.productid = p1.productid 
> WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2019' AND '2020'
> GROUP by c.customerid2, c.name,p.productid,p.productname
> ORDER by total DESC) t2
> ```
>
> ```
> | json_result                                                                       |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"product": "15 car", "customer": {"name": "jon", "total": 10, "customerid": 1}}  |
> | {"product": "15 car", "customer": {"name": "steve", "total": 5, "customerid": 2}} |
> | {"product": "3 boat", "customer": {"name": "ned", "total": 2, "customerid": 4}}   |
> | {"product": "3 boat", "customer": {"name": "ted", "total": 1, "customerid": 3}}   |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     json_object('product', CONCAT( total_sum,' ',productname), 'customer',json_result) json_result
> FROM
>   (SELECT  
>       productname
>       ,totaL_SUM
>       ,JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('customerid', customerid2, 'name', name,'total', total)) json_result
>   FROM
>       (SELECT 
>         c.customerid2, c.name,p.productname,SUM(qty) total, p1.total_sum
>       FROM customer c inner JOIN products p ON c.customerid2 = p.customerid1
>       inner Join (SELECT productid, SUM(qty) total_sum FROM products GROUP BY productid) p1 
>         ON p.productid = p1.productid 
>       WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2019' AND '2020'
>       GROUP by c.customerid2, c.name,p.productid,p.productname
>       ORDER by total DESC) t2
>   GROUP BY productname,total_sum) t3
> ```
>
> ```
> | json_result                                                                                                                        |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"product": "3 boat", "customer": [{"name": "ned", "total": 2, "customerid": 4}, {"name": "ted", "total": 1, "customerid": 3}]}    |
> | {"product": "15 car", "customer": [{"name": "jon", "total": 10, "customerid": 1}, {"name": "steve", "total": 5, "customerid": 2}]} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b046eef61357f610474382172c28fc3)*

Comment: i cant remake the tables. thats not an option

Comment: What do you mean by you can not remake?  Post your php code and i will try o resolve your Problem

Comment: you want me to add new values to the table?

Comment: Look the answer give you all the data you wanted, i don't know what you wnat  to do woth it. As i pointed out you can use the result set in any language and reshape the outpu. But as you can see, all the data is available

Comment: I made an json Object out of it, more i can not do